# BUG? wxpython TreeCtrl.GetParent ---> too many arguments

Tags: wxpython

wxPython 4.1.1 treeCtrl throws error Window.GetParent(): too many arguments

when GetParent(self.item) is called

are there any workarounds for this?

```
import  wx

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id = -1):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id)

        self.tree = wx.TreeCtrl(self, -1, wx.Point(0, 0), wx.Size(210, 250),
                           wx.TR_DEFAULT_STYLE | wx.NO_BORDER)

        self.root = self.tree.AddRoot("The Root Item")

        for x in range(15):
            child = self.tree.AppendItem(self.root, "Item %d" % x)
            for y in range(5):
                last = self.tree.AppendItem(child, "item %d-%s" % (x, chr(ord("a")+y)))
                for z in range(5):
                    item = self.tree.AppendItem(last,  "item %d-%s-%d" % (x, chr(ord("a")+y), z))

        self.tree.Expand(self.root)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TREE_SEL_CHANGED, self.OnSelChanged, self.tree)


    def OnSelChanged(self, event):
        self.item = event.GetItem()
        print(self.tree.GetParent(self.item))
        event.Skip()
class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = Frame(None)
        self.frame.Show(True)
        return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MyApp()
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry a hot day!!

**!!GetItemParent!!** does the trick